# How to stop invisible console log in next js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using react-redux in my next js application. I'm calling the request to create a store when there is a request in my _app.js but there is some message logged in my console every time I route to a page.

This is its screenshot [image: The log]

I feel this is a bit annoying, I've search all over my code but I can't find what is logging here. Here is my _app.js for reference.

```js
import Layout from '../components/Layout/Layout';
import '../styles/globals.css';
import { initializeParse } from '@parse/react-ssr';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import withRedux from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import React from 'react';
import store from '../redux/store';
import App from 'next/app'
import TimeAgo from 'javascript-time-ago'

import en from 'javascript-time-ago/locale/en'
import ru from 'javascript-time-ago/locale/ru'

TimeAgo.addLocale(en)



class MyApp extends App{

  static async getInitialProps({Component,ctx}){

    const appProps =  Component.getInitialProps ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx) : {} ;


    return {appProps: appProps};

  }

  render() {
      
    const {Component,appProps} = this.props;



    return(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Layout>

          <Component {...appProps} />

        </Layout>
      </Provider>
    );
  }

}

const makeStore = () => store;



export default withRedux(makeStore)(MyApp);
```

I would like find out what's going on

Comment: Are you using Next redux wrapper ?

Comment: Yes I am using next redux wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with `next-redux-wrapper`.

Ref.:
https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper/issues/385
https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper/pull/384

It is fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper/commit/9b041f8258745f2402a88f542dd379eae37a8220), [release](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper/releases/tag/7.0.2).

Please upgrade to `v7.0.2` to resolve this problem.